# GridView in Listview can not display well after refreshed

Tags: android

I add a gridview as headerview of listview,when i change gridview's content, it's height does't changes,I can only see a part of gridview's new content.I have tried invalidate,but it does't work.In the gridview,i click the more button,and then change the adapter of gridview,but i can see only a part of new content of gridview,and when i call geidview.getHeight,(),it does't change

Comment: Have you tried manually calling notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: yes ,i have ,the question is that the gridview has changed,but it's height does't,it's still the inital height

Comment: can you show me your gridview xml code ?

Comment: <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_invited"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/r_invited"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
             />

Comment: refer this link, I hope is usefull for you  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listing-images-in-gridview-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

Comment: i have checked ,but it seems not very usefull,but still thanks

Answer (score 0):

gridView.getHeight() will not return the height of the gridView. It would return 0. This is because the gridView would get layed out only after the view has been rendered. You could check the android documentation for this.

If you want to add the header, then set a minHeight on the gridView something like :

```
<GridView
    android:minHeight="5dp" />
```

This will ensure that the header has a minHeight of 5dp.